# Color problem while trying to plot KMeans clusters

Tags: python, matplotlib, machine-learning, k-means

I am trying to plot my data with a colours related to the clusters as shown below:

[image]

However, when I write this code it shows as below:

```
model = KMeans(n_clusters = 2)
model.fit(projected_data)
labels = model.predict(projected_data)
plt.scatter(projected_data[0],projected_data[1],c='red')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Looking online, I found changing the `c='red'` to `c=labels` would fix the problem, but when ever I change the code to `plt.scatter(projected_data[0],projected_data[1],c=labels)` it gives me this error:

`'c' argument has 2 elements, which is inconsistent with 'x' and 'y' with size 6.`

How can I make the colours change dynamically (Not having to type an array of strings 6 times like `c=['red','blue'...]`) to get a colour for each cluster?

In case you need it to test it yourself, projected_data variable equals

```
[[ 4  4 -6  3  1 -5]
 [ 0 -3  2 -1  5 -4]]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's expecting a list.  You can see an example here where we use kmeans.labels_ as the color parameter.  You could change the color palette or map the cluster labels to strings of the color you want.

```
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
import numpy as np
X = np.array([[1, 2], [1, 4], [1, 0],
              [10, 2], [10, 4], [10, 0]])
kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=2, random_state=0).fit(X)

x,y = X.T

print(kmeans.labels_)
plt.scatter(x,y, c=kmeans.labels_);
```

Output

```
[1 1 1 0 0 0]
```

[image]